Unsure as to what tests, how, and potential in a research scenario
There are three classrooms of students of different grades. I want to analyze what variables of these influenced likelihood of scoring 0 on a test. The factors are: grade (8, 9 or 10) and stress level scale from 0 to 3.
Of the students who scored 0, I want to compare those things statistically. How can I do this? I have Excel and Jamovi (an R software). I want mostly to make it into max two graphs and most importantly find out if there is a significant difference in students scoring 0 between stress levels and ages.
This is an analogy I came up with for a project I am working on but am not allowed to share--- but this is the same statistical issue I am having. My data looks like this:

Test score (continuous decimal variable)--> list of scores
Stress level (ordinal variable, 0 1 2 or 3)
Grade (ordinal) 8, 9, or 10


Are all students, even though in different grades, taking the same test? This would be a bit unusual? But if not, comparing the scores makes little sense? Can you clarify?

It is not students, as I was saying later on this is an analogy for a project I cannot share online. In this case, yes, the students are taking the same test.

If test score is continuous, then, in most situations, getting a 0 would be very odd. But, one thing you could consider is logistic regression after dichotomizing the score. I don't think this is likely to be right ... but, since you can't tell us the real situation, I'm not sure.
